SharePoint - Sum Values in a Column based on a Value in Another Column
I'm fairly new to SharePoint, but have some experience.  Using my "Irradiation Entries" list, I am wanting to sum the values in "Total uAh" for the corresponding "Rabbit Body ID" values in a separate view or separate list called "Rabbit Log". What would be the best way to go about this?
Example
I'm not sure where to start.  Thanks for the help in advance!!!

I have no idea but I pasted your question into Google and got this, does it help? https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Sum-Values-in-one-column-based-on-value-in-another-column-same/td-p/2370581

Here are steps:
1.Click Rabbit Body ID column -> Group by Rabbit Body ID.

2.Click Total uAh column -> Totals -> Sum.

3.Result:


you can set it in the "Edit current view" screen. Upper right corner, where the default "All items" view is shown with the three horizontal lines. Then scroll down to the "Totals" section where you can set which field should be calculated and how (number fields have more mathematical options (like sum or average), others have only count).
